# Ramification for subgroups of Lubin-Tate formal group

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a finite field extension and $E/\mathcal{O}_K$ be the local N\'eron model of a CM elliptic curve with CM by $\mathcal{O}_F$ and let $G\subseteq E[p^n]$ be a subgroup over $\mathcal{O}_K$ of order $p^n$ which we assume to be cyclic. We assume that $p$ is inert in $\mathcal{O}_F$ so that $E[p^\infty]$ is a $1$-dimensional $p$-divisible group of height $2$. Hence we can write
$$G = \text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K[x]/g(x)).$$
Let $s:\mathcal{O}_K\to E$ be the identity section. One can compute from the explicit form of $G$ above that
$$s^*\Omega^1_{G/\mathcal{O}_K} = \frac{\mathcal{O}_K}{\prod_{\lambda\in G\setminus \{0\}}\lambda}$$
thus
$$\#s^*\Omega_{G/\mathcal{O}_K} = p^{f\sum_{\lambda\in G\setminus \{0\}}v_{\pi_K}(\lambda)}$$
where $f$ denotes the inertia degree of $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Since $G\subseteq E[p^n]$, it follows that we can compute $v_{\pi_K}(\lambda)$ from the Lubin-Tate group law on $E[p^\infty]$ since $\lambda$ must also be a zero of that.

We use a Newton polygon for the group law
$$[p](X) = pX + X^q$$
where $q = \mathrm{Nm}(\pi_F)=p^2$. Then after a bit of induction, the slopes give the valuation as:
$$v_{\pi_K}(\lambda) = \frac{v_{\pi_K}(p)}{q^r - q^{r-1}}$$
for a $\lambda$ of exact order $p^r$.

We let $\Phi(r)$ denote the number of elements of $G$ of exact $p$-order $r$. Then
$$\sum_{\lambda\in G\setminus\{0\}}v_{\pi_K}(\lambda) = v_{\pi_K}(p)\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\Phi(r)}{q^r-q^{r-1}} = v_{\pi_K}(p)\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{p^r-p^{r-1}}{p^{2r}-p^{2r-2}} = \frac{v_{\pi_K}(p)}{p+1}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{p^{r-1}}.$$

I want a geometric interpretation of this. In particular, if I choose a filtration
$$0\subseteq G_1\subseteq\cdots\subseteq G_n = G$$
where each subquotient $G^{(r)}$ is a group of order $p$, then we should have
$$\#\log s^*\Omega^1_{G^{(r)}/\mathcal{O}_K} = f\left(\frac{v_{\pi_K}(p)}{p+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{p^{r-1}}\right)\log p.$$

Is there a way to obtain this without using the formal group law of $E[p^\infty]$? In particular, I am interested in understanding how and why the factor $p^{-(r-1)}$ arises, and whether there is a geometric way of seeing this.